# Advanced math operations in TapScript?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, bitcoin-core-development, bip, taproot

Hence BIP 342 proposes to enable opcodes like OP_MOD, OP_DIV, OP_MUL is it possible to perform advanced math operations like EC point addition/multiplication in a script size of up to 10kB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIP 342 does not add any of these opcodes, and it is not possible to perform elliptic curve operations in it.

The only new/changed opcode semantics in BIP342 are:

- Schnorr signatures instead of ECDSA.
- OP_CHECKSIGADD instead of OP_CHECKMULTISIG(VERIFY).
- OP_SUCCESSx opcodes for future extensibility
- Unknown pubkey types for future extensibility.
- Changes in resource accounting/limits.

Comment: Got it. One or more OP_SUCCESSx opcodes could potentially function as OP_MOD, OP_DIV, OP_MUL in a future soft fork right?

Comment: Yes, potentially.